# Tree listing for categorys

Tags: php, wordpress

I have an array like this

```
Array
(
[0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [cat_id] => 3
        [cat_name] => sample 3
        [cat_description] => 
        [cat_folder] => sample_3
        [cat_path] => sample_3
        [cat_parent] => 0
        [cat_num_files] => 0
        [cat_num_files_total] => 0
        [cat_user_roles] => 
        [cat_owner] => 1
        [cat_icon] => 
        [cat_exclude_browser] => 0
        [cat_order] => 0
    )

[1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [cat_id] => 2
        [cat_name] => sample 2
        [cat_description] => 
        [cat_folder] => sample_2
        [cat_path] => sample_3/sample_2
        [cat_parent] => 3
        [cat_num_files] => 0
        [cat_num_files_total] => 0
        [cat_user_roles] => 
        [cat_owner] => 1
        [cat_icon] => 
        [cat_exclude_browser] => 0
        [cat_order] => 0
    )

)
```

I need to list these like

```
-sample 3
--sample 2
---sample 4
```

There is no limit for the link depth, a category may have 5 deep, it may be 10. I have tried this in a `foreach` loop but failed to retrieve a list like a tree.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend recursion, becouse you don't know how nested it will be. Bellow is example of recursion function.

```
function genCat($parentCat){
    echo $parentCat->name;
    if ($parentCat->haveChildren){
        foreach($parentCat->children as $child){
            genCat($child);
        }
    }
}
```

This is just example, hope it helps